# How to Create a Simple Batch file for Application Uninstall via CMD?

Tags: batch-file

I am inquiring assistance on creating a simple batch file in order to help field techs at my job remove the Microsoft Exchange Management Console via CMD batch. But for some reason i have been unsuccessful at being to accomplish this.

To my understanding its a matter of changing directories and running a uninstaller.

If i do it manually Run CMD as Admin and copy and paste

> cd %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Exchange Server\v14\bin\setup.com /m:uninstall

This works flawlessly however when trying to compose it into a batch no go.

```
@echo off 

cd D/ c:\

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Exchange Server\v14\bin\setup.com /m:uninstall
```

And in theory i am assuming this should do it simple and so i thought but i can not get this thing going. I know i am missing something.

Can someone shed some light on the subject i would be most appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: `cd D/ c:\ ` should be `cd /d c:\ ` (change-drives switch is `/d`) or maybe `cd /d %SystemDrive%:\ `. But the whole `cd` line is not needed since you then run a command with a full path anchored at `%ProgramFiles%`. Also, there is no way that `cd %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Exchange Server\v14\bin\setup.com /m:uninstall` worked "flawlessly" at the cmd prompt. Normally, that would give you a `cd` error about an invalid path, but in any case it would never ever execute `setup.com /m:uninstall`. You'll help yourself get quicker/better help next time if you posted information that's actually valid.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your response, this indeed did work but without the cd. Also I did mean :d as that changes the drive letter for me all the time they where both typos on my part. But pasting that path into CMD will get you there and then typing setup.com /m:uninstall begins the process. If you have a moment I suggest you install the management console and try it sometime. Sorry about the typos I'll make sure to proof read it next time thanks

Answer (score 0):

CD is the command to 'Change Directory'. Try this line to perform the uninstall.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Exchange Server\v14\bin\setup.com" /m:uninstall
```

You need the quotes to handle the spaces in that path. And it is good practice. For future posts remember that it is helpful if you indicate what error or result you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply RGUggisberg that worked, what i don't understand is aren't "path" characters sometimes replaced by spaces, unless they are part of a string?

There was no real error hence why i didn't list any the CMD opened and then closed i tried pause to see if i can capture and syntax errors but nothing.

Wouldn't cd d/ c:\ put me in C:\ afterword asking it to change directory into the corespoding dir?

Comment: I agree with comments posted by @dxiv... there is no way that this actually worked from the CMD line. You were trying to combine commands and the CD served no purpose.